# Block Diagonal Matrices - GMRES vs Conjugate Gradient

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose that my matrix A is nonsymmetric, nonsingular and is also block diagonal using 2x2 blocks.

The jth block is $\begin{bmatrix}1 & j-1 \\ 0 & 1\\ \end{bmatrix}$ with $j = 1,...,\dfrac{n}{2}$.

If I am looking to use both Conjugate Gradient method and GMRES method, which do you think will converge faster for this block diagonal matrix?

Here are my thoughts: GMRES is appropriate and preferred for dealing with nonsymmetric, nonsingular matrices so I am leaning towards GMRES as being the faster convergence as opposed to CG. However, I'm not quite sure if having the matrix be block diagonal has any effect on convergence between the two methods.

Any help and insight is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This matrix is a very special case. You can write the solution down directly by just a set of pairwise multiply-subtract without any involving numerical algorithm.

Comment: Conjugate gradient only assured to work for symmetric matrices. But you can rewrite to solve the normal equations $A^TAx = A^Tb$ instead of $Ax = b$, but I doubt it would be efficient for this problem.

Comment: If I understand the description of $A$, all you need to do is $n/2$ tiny backward solves.

Answer (score 1):

Conjugate Gradient only works on symmetric matrices, so we have to make the problem about solving a symmetric matrix equation. We can do that for example by instead solving the normal equations:

$${\bf Ax = b} \Rightarrow ({\bf A}^T{\bf A}){\bf x = \bf A}^T{\bf b}$$

However in general this will produce an eigensystem with maximum "scattered" eigenvalues. The very worst for Conjugate Gradient - of which convergence behaviour instead benefits from eigenvalues being "clustered" close together.

I doubt GMRES would be any better but I haven't thought too much about it.

---

The matrix can be solved by making row operations; $j-1$ times the second row and then subtract from the first row. Repeat for each block. Basically one scalar multiplication and subtraction per two rows and then we have solved the equation system. It can't get much cheaper than that, computationally speaking.

---

**EDIT** A probably better way to realize this is to use the geometric series:
$$({\bf I-A})^{-1} = {\bf I+A+ \underset{=0 \text{ (nilpotence) }}{\underbrace{A^2+\cdots}} }$$ coupled with the fact that we can make $\bf A$ nilpotent of order 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So would you say having matrix A as block-diagonal doesn't necessarily have a significant impact on faster convergence for GMRES or CG? 

But because the matrix is nonsymmetric and nonsingular, GMRES would most likely converge faster than CG?

Comment: CG won't converge at all for this matrix as it requires positive definiteness to converge. Block diagonal will imply sparse which means fast to multiply with vectors making them fast to run each iteration with. But that does not guarantee any bound on the number of iterations for convergence.